# Epson Printers cannot use after Window Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, printer, windows-update

After yesterday Windows Update,Epson printers cannot be used start from this morning. All the PC in Windows 7 and Windows 10 cannot detect these Epson printers.
Any solution for this?